# Сменить title Action bar'a

Tags: java, android, activity, android-toolbar

Есть класс, который никак не связан с MainActivity, но в нём происходят действия, которые должны менять заголовок Action bar'a
Подскажите, как лучше реализовать?

Answer (score 3):

1. Создайте интерфейс.
2. Реализуйте его в активити.
3. В реализации задавайте заголовок тулбара.
4. Передайте ссылку на активити/интерфейс в ваш класс
5. В нужный момент вызовите метод интерфейса.